# Не работает реклама от Admob на Adobe AIR

Tags: admob, actionscript, adobe, adobe-air

Столкнулся со странной ситуацией: у меня есть два компьютера, на одном и на другом установлены одинаковые версии Adobe Animate CC. Но появилась проблема. Внедрил в своё приложение плагин от admoba для рекламы. Собираю .apk на первом компьютере и всё работает нормально, реклама отображается. Но вот когда собираю на втором пк, рекламы нет. Уже пробовал переустанавливать, всё работает, а вот реклама не отображается. Что может быть не так со вторым пк, ведь настройки для приложения одинаковы на обоих компьютерах?

Пробовал чистить кэш Adobe Animate. Не помогло.